# Deploying Numba gives a StopIteration error which gives no clear hint on how to fix the code?

Tags: python, numba

I have a python code that scales really badly with n so much so that for n=50 the time is in seconds but for n=1000 is many hours.

I therefore tried to use Numba to speed it up but have only been dealing with a lot of errors. I have managed to rectify the errors so far but suddenly now I have the error of "StopIteration" and that gives no hint on what bug to look for in the code.

Here is the non-Numba version (with the output which is what I am trying to get with Numba):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *

counter=0
n=100
iter=0
np.random.seed(0)
Zinitial=np.random.normal(0,1,size=(2,n))[0,:]
np.random.seed(1)
Pinitial=np.random.normal(0,1,size=(2,n))[1,:]
SPIN=np.zeros(n,dtype=int);
SPIN[int(n/2):]=0;
SPIN[:int(n/2)]=1;

SP = np.array(sorted(np.array([np.array([i,j,k]) for i, j,k in zip(Zinitial, Pinitial,SPIN)]),
                key=lambda x: x[0]))


print("Initial energy : ",(np.sum(SP[:,0]**2)+np.sum(SP[:,1]**2))/2 )

total_time=0
Tmax=10
alf=sqrt(10)

while total_time<Tmax:
  T=[]
  for j in range(n-1):
    b=(SP[j+1,1]-SP[j,1])/(SP[j+1,0]-SP[j,0])
    val1=b+sqrt(b**2+2)
    val2=b-sqrt(b**2+2)
    if val1>0:
      T.append(val1)
    else:
      T.append(val2)
  
  T=np.array(T)
  dt=min(T[T>0])
  total_time=dt+total_time
  indix=list(T).index(dt)
  
  SP0=SP[:,0].copy()
  SP[:,0]=SP0*cos(dt)+SP[:,1]*sin(dt)
  SP[:,1]=SP[:,1]*cos(dt)-SP0*sin(dt)
  
  prel=(SP[indix,1]-SP[indix+1,1])/2
  rcoeff=1/(1+(prel*alf)**2)
  
  SP[[indix,indix+1]]=SP[[indix+1,indix]]
  SP=np.array(sorted(SP,key=lambda x:x[0]))
  
  rand_value=np.random.random()
  rcoeff=1/(1+(prel*alf)**2)
  
  if rcoeff>rand_value and SP[indix,2]!=SP[indix+1,2]:
    counter=counter+1
    SP[indix,2],SP[indix+1,2]=SP[indix+1,2],SP[indix,2]
 
print("total_time = ",total_time)
print("n= ", n) 
print("rate = ", 2*counter/(n*(total_time)))
OUTPUT:

Initial energy :  95.56821008840404
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:29: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:31: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
total_time =  10.000079819065235
n=  100
rate =  3.2079743942482555
final energy :  95.5682100884033
```

Here is the devil Numba version with the error output:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *
from numba import jit
from numba import types,typed

@jit(nopython=True)
def f(SP, alf,Tmax, n):
  
  counter=0
  total_time=0
  T=np.empty(0,dtype=np.float64)
  while total_time<Tmax:
    for j in range(n-1):
      b=(SP[j+1,1]-SP[j,1])/(SP[j+1,0]-SP[j,0])
      val1=b+sqrt(b**2+2)
      val2=b-sqrt(b**2+2)
      if val1>0:
        np.append(T,val1)
      else:
        np.append(T,val2)
    
    dt=min(T[T>0])
    total_time=dt+total_time
    indix,=np.where(T==dt)[0]
    SP0=SP[:,0].copy()
    SP[:,0]=SP0*cos(dt)+SP[:,1]*sin(dt)
    SP[:,1]=SP[:,1]*cos(dt)-SP0*sin(dt)
    prel=(SP[indix,1]-SP[indix+1,1])/2;
    rcoeff=1/(1+(prel*alf)**2);
    for h in range(n-1):
      for z in range(SP.shape[1]):
        SP[h, z], SP[h + 1, z] = SP[h + 1, z], SP[h, z]

    
    SP=SP[SP[:, 0].argsort()]
    
    rand_value=np.random.random()
    rcoeff=1/(1+(prel*alf)**2)
    if rcoeff>rand_value and SP[indix,2]!=SP[indix+1,2]:
      counter=counter+1
      SP[indix,2],SP[indix+1,2]=SP[indix+1,2],SP[indix,2]
  
  rate=2*counter/(n*total_time)
  energy=np.sum((SP[:,0]**2+SP[:,1]**2)/2)  
  return rate,energy



if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    n=100
    Tmax=10
    alf=sqrt(10)
    np.random.seed(0)
    Zinitial=np.random.normal(0,1,size=(2,n))[0,:]
    np.random.seed(1)
    Pinitial=np.random.normal(0,1,size=(2,n))[1,:]
    SPIN=np.zeros(n,dtype=int);
    SPIN[int(n/2):]=0;
    SPIN[:int(n/2)]=1;
    SP = np.array(sorted(np.array([np.array([i,j,k]) for i, j,k in zip(Zinitial, Pinitial,SPIN)]),
                key=lambda x: x[0]))

    print("Initial energy : ",(np.sum(SP[:,0]**2)+np.sum(SP[:,1]**2))/2 )
    rate,energy = f(SP, alf, Tmax, n)
    print("Rate of collision per particle = ",rate)
    print("Final energy : ",energy)
OUTPUT:

Initial energy :  95.56821008840404
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-9d8cc152e0a8> in <module>()
     64 
     65     print("Initial energy : ",(np.sum(SP[:,0]**2)+np.sum(SP[:,1]**2))/2 )
---> 66     rate,energy = f(SP, alf, Tmax, n)
     67     print("Rate of collision per particle = ",rate)
     68     print("Final energy : ",energy)

StopIteration: 
Pardon me for dumping huge chunks but I don't know which part has the bug.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many problems in the Numba code:

- The result of `np.append` is not assigned so the instruction does nothing: `np.append` is not an in-place operation. *This is the reason why you get a StopIteration*: the expression `dt=min(T[T>0])` fails because T is empty.
- `np.append` should never be use in a loop since it create a new array for every iteration resulting in a slow quadratic execution. Use a preallocated array (best solution) or a list (less efficient).
- There are out-of-bound access causing crashes and undefined behaviours. Please use the flags `debug=True` and `boundscheck=True` to track them. For example `indix` is set to 228 (which seems legit since T.shape is 297) while `SP.shape` is `(100,3)` so `SP[indix,1]` fails. Numba is design to be fast by default so it does not track out-of-bound access by default which can cause surprising behaviour since an out-of-bound is an undefined behaviour and the JIT can make crazy assumption in this case. I also strongly advise you to print the values of the variable so to check deterministic computations (ie. not random-based ones) are the same in Numba.

Note that `np.random.seed` does not affect the Numba seed (Numba use a separate seed that is not synchronised with Numpy). Thus, random numbers will likely differ between Numba and a pure-Numpy code.

Comment: Thanks! I will work from your hints on my own . What do u mean when you say "a preallocated array"? Do you mean I initialize it with zeros and somehow replace them with the values I want to append?

Comment: Yes, but without the zero-initialization which is not needed. You can use `arr = np.empty(total_size)` and then do in the loop: `arr[cursor] = value` followed by `cursor += 1`.

Comment: When python encounters a division by zero it stores infinity but with Numba that does not happen ... an error message for "division by zero" shows up. Do I have to manually look at this condition with an if statement in the denominator?

Comment: @Lost Try `1 / 0` in a Python interpreter... it throws `ZeroDivisionError`, no Numba required.

Comment: @CrazyChucky Yes. But in some of my previous programs I was getting `inf`.

Comment: Note that `1/0` `1.0/0.0` and `np.float64(1) / np.float64(0)` are 3 differents cases resulting in different behaviours. The last gives `np.inf` but with a warning: "*divide by zero encountered in double_scalars*". A division by zeros is generally an issue in a program, not a normal case. Relying on it is not a generally good idea. Infinities tends to create NaN values that often spread everywhere causing even more issues. `np.float64(0) / np.float64(0)` result in NaN like Inf-Inf for example or even Inf/Inf as well as Inf*0 !

Comment: Numba should respect the IEEE-754 standard unless you use the flag `fastmath=True`. Otherwise, you can fill an issue on the github repository. Numpy make many check to warn users but not always so surprising results can be obtained on non-mainstream machines (eg. M1 and POWER processors). I strongly advise you to design a code so such a case do not happen. You can use assertions if needed. If you do not use special values like NaN or Inf nor care about FP associativity, then you can speed up codes with fastmath which can sometimes help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. They are very helpful. Th reason I am facing these divisions by zeros is because I am using an approximation of arctan instead of `np.arctan2` function. It's really surprising to see how computationally taxing arctan2 is .. even with Numba it runs for long

Comment: @JérômeRichard I fixed the code following your advice and it worked well (giving close results to analyatical ones) but only till n=500. After that it shows a value error. I have put an edit of my updated code if in case you can spare a tad bit more time on this question. Note: I can see the error happens at `indix,=np.where(T==dt)[0]` line but it works till n=500 case and it will be weird to print it for n=600 case to check it with such big output